# How to acess the html of a page on Microweber?

Tags: templates, content-management-system

F‌irst of all, sorry for my bad english.

I started to use the Dream Template and I added some changes on the template files and in the custom.css to make the site like I want to.
But I am facing a problem.

#### Image of my actual navbar

[image: Image of my actual navbar]

This is how my menu looks like, the problem is that I need that 3 of the sub categories of the menu have each one a different background than the rest of them.

#### The 3 Sub-Categories I need to change

[image: The 3 Sub-Categories I need to change]

I need that these three be different from all the others, but how i do that if I don't see the menu on the HTML Editor, and I cannot edit that on the header.php of the template?

Comment: Look at your rendered code in the browsers text or development view and see if these items have ids or classes associated with them. If they do then your custom.css could override them. If not, then you might need to do more research into your CMS.

Comment: They all have the same class and dont have id, the only thing that changes it is the data-item-id atribute. So i guess i am screwed anyway

Answer (score 0):

So Microweber Support have answered to me and showed me how to do it.

U can style using the data-item-id atribute on CSS (I never have learned about it)
So i will leave this topic here for people that can face the same problem than i haved.

Thanks a lot guys.